# Join of two files introduces extraneous newline

Tags: awk

**Update:** I figured out the reason for the extraneous newline. I created `file1` and `file2` on a Windows machine. Windows adds `<cr><newline>` to the end of each line. So, for example, the first record in file1 is not this:

```
Bill <tab> 25 <newline>
```

Instead, it is this:

```
Bill <tab> 25 <cr><newline>
```

So when I set `a[Bill]` to `$2` I am actually setting it to `$2<cr>`.

I used a hex editor and removed all of the `<cr>` symbols in `file1` and `file2`. Now the AWK program works as desired.

I have seen the SO posts on using AWK to do a natural join of two files. I took one of the solutions and am trying to get it to work. Alas, I have been unsuccessful. I am hoping you can tell me what I am doing wrong.

**Note: I appreciate other solutions, but what I really want is to understand why *my* AWK program doesn't work (i.e., why/how an extraneous newline is being introduced).**

I want to do a join of these two files:

**file1** (name, tab, age):

```
Bill    25
John    24
Mary    21
```

**file2** (name, tab, marital-status)

```
Bill    divorced
Glenn   married
John    married
Mary    single
```

When joined, I expect to see this (name, tab, age, tab, marital-status):

```
Bill    25  divorced
John    24  married
Mary    21  single
```

Notice that file2 has a person named Glenn, but file1 doesn't. No record in file1 joins to it.

My AWK program almost produces that result. But, for reasons I don't understand, the marital-status value is on the next line:

```
Bill    25
divorced
John    24
married
Mary    21
single
```

Here is my AWK program:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = '\t' }
     NR == FNR { a[$1] = ($1 in a? a[$1] OFS : "")$2; next }
     $1 in a { $0 = $0 OFS a[$1]; delete a[$1]; print }' file2 file1  > joined_file1_file2
```

Comment: Your ternary puts a value in `a` if one is there and puts a blank (plus the status) there if it's empty. I would use an associative array as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504491/26428)

Comment: Also if you look at my answer posted well before tour latest edit, I included sub call just for that as I suspected all along presence of DOS line ending

Comment: See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: You should have included in your example a name in file1 that doesn't exist in file2 so we can see how you want that treated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/\r$/, "")}
FNR == NR {m[$1]=$2; next} {print $0, m[$1]}' file2 file1

Bill    25  divorced
John    24  married
Mary    21  single
```

Here:

- Using `sub(/\r$/, "")` to remove any DOS line ending
- If `$1` doesn't exist in mapping `m` then `m[$1]` will be an empty string so we can simplify awk processing

Comment: Although the OP didn't include this possibility, it should be noted that this will print lines from the age file that don't exist in the status file (which could be a desired result).